# ReSharper 2020.2.4 fails on C# 9.0 records

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper, c#-9.0

I'm playing with a new `record` feature in a console app. I'm using my VS Community 16.8.0 + R# 2020.2.4 trial.

### C# code

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Person("firstname", "lastname");
            Console.WriteLine($"test.FirstName: {test.FirstName} test.LastName: {test.LastName}");
        }
    }

    public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
}
```

### Csproj file

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

The code could be compiled and it runs.

[image: C# 9.0 record issue]

### Problem

The thing is that IntelliSense does not recognise the record itself. VS underlines the record definition and does not recognise its use despite the fact that the program itself can be compiled.

**What am I doing wrong?**

[image: Intellisense fails]

### Note

VS somehow recognise a typo in record definition/use.

[image: Typo is recognised]

Comment: That red highlighting seems to be a ReSharper problem. Do you have any similar issues when you disable ReSharper?

Comment: I've tried to disable R#, but I can't find this option in VS settings any more.

Comment: _"What am I doing wrong?"_ -- expecting Resharper to fully support the records feature immediately after it was released? The problem isn't reproducible for me; in my stock installation of VS2019 16.8, Intellisense works fine for everything in your code example, including the `Person` type. I can't prove the issue is related to Resharper, but it seems very likely.

Comment: Resharper 2020.3 early access is the only option you have if you want to use the new C# 9 syntax bits and Resharper at the same time. And yes, the problems you've shown is Resharper, not Visual Studio.

Comment: I never had a problem with R# and new feature before. Records are out from May at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have the same "problem", I should say?

ReSharper still does not get it. Records are still broken as hell for ReSharper. As long as this goes, I cannot use ReSharper in classes where records are defined or used. Too many false errors. Switching ReSharper on and off depending on the file is ridiculously annoying, which leads to mostly ReSharper deactivated. Damn. Why the heck. I also completely removed everything ReSharper related and did a clean install again. Same result with the newest version. C# (preview) can be used since months and they still did not get it managed. Wow.

@KUTlime go to "extensions" menu and select ReSharper, then to "options...". Second way of doing this is right click the black circle at the bottom right corner and click "Customize...", there you go.

Edit: Upgrading to 2020.3 EAP7 (Early Access Preview) solved the issue for me (and the preview is slower than before).

Answer (score 7):

ReSharper 2020.2.4 does not support the new C# 9 features. Try the latest version ([2020.3](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/download-thanks.html?code=RSU&platform=windows)). Any further issues you have with ReSharper should best be taken up with JetBrains directly.

Comment: This solved it for me. Remember if you go EAP and you're in a team environment, either everyone on the team will have to enable the EAP or you're going to get some team members scratching their heads at your red-squiggly underlined lovely new "records". As an alternative, to use new C# 9 features in isolation with a non EAP RE#, you can add ```// ReSharper disable All```  to the top of the file - of course you will lose all RE# help for the file with the new C# 9 stuff in, but it might be better than forcing everyone onto the EAP

Comment: @AdamDiament - ReSharper 2020.3 has been released now so you and your team can all upgrade to the latest version.